# Is there a way to automatically add photos to Address Book contacts?

Tags: macos, photos, facebook, address-book

I'm looking for a way to automatically add photos to my Address Book contacts, from sources such as

- Google (as auto-fetched to e.g. Adium contacts),
- Gravatars,
- Facebook photos,
- etc.

Especially for the new Address Book in Lion.

Any ideas?

Comment: Google [syncs](http://imgur.com/qbRXc) with the Address book (also the photos).

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook, LinkedIn and Twitter apps on iOS can sync photos to the Address Book, iTunes or your Mac (via iCloud syncing).